# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ as a rectangular lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-geometry

I have been asked to consider $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ as a rectangular lattice. I have no idea what this means, though? I've plotted some points, and I see that the ring is comprised of rectangles with sides of length $1$ and $\sqrt2$.

Comment: I think it might just mean consider as a rank 2 $\mathbb{Z}$-module with basis $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: Correction: basis $\{1,\sqrt{-2}\}$.

Comment: Since $\sqrt{-2}^2 = -2$ then the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] =\{ \sum_{n=0}^d c_n \sqrt{-2}^n, c_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is just $\mathbb{Z}+ \sqrt{-2}\mathbb{Z}= \{ a+ b \sqrt{-2}, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\} $